# VBA Macro Installer for MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have created a macro that uses multiple modules, class modules, and forms. I am looking for a way to bundle install all these files to the Project Global Template (Global.MPT) without having to manually adding each file through VBA ide. Does anyone know a good solution to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Shoebagel! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Here is a useful post for Excel, this might work for Project. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

Answer (score 0):

The application method [OrganizerMoveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.organizermoveitem) can be used to copy modules, class modules, and forms (also tables, views, [etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjorganizer)) from one project to another, including the global.mpt file.

Here's an example:

```
Application.OrganizerMoveItem pjModules, ThisProject.Name, "global.mpt", "frmTest", False
```

Also try searching SO for other [questions about ms project global file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5Dglobal.mpt).